# RBGLuminanceSource.toString is throwing StackOverflowError when dimensions of image are big

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I cannot understand why I'm getting StackoverflowError. I'm trying to build bitmap from an image to scan QR code. **source** from decode() method is build in standard way:

```
if (bitmap != null) {
      int[] intArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
      bitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
      return new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), intArray);
```

And than decode() throws error:
*source: Method threw 'java.lang'StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.google.zxing.RGBLuminanceSource.toString()*

```
private QRCodeMultiReader qrCodeReader;
      
public void decode(LuminanceSource source, ScannerResultListener resultListener) {
        try {
          BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
          String decodedContent = qrCodeReader.decode(bitmap, hints).getText();
          Timber.d("qr code scanner has successfully decoded content: [%s]", decodedContent);
          resultListener.onScanningSuccess(decodedContent);
        } catch (ReaderException re) {
          Timber.d(re.getMessage(), "qr code scanner can not decode code");
          resultListener.onScanningFailure();
        } finally {
          qrCodeReader.reset();
        }
      }
```

It happens only when I upload image with big dimensions (e. g. 1242x2688px). When I downsize uploaded image to height for example 2160px, everything is ok., and image is scanned properly.
I cannot find anything about zxing dimensional restrictions.

Does anybody know why is that?

Comment: Can you provide the full stack track and the full code of `decode()`. SOE are often caused by cyclic calls, method A calls method B which calls method A as instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I had to upgrade Zxing libs to newer version. In my problem 3.3.1 was sufficient.
But newer libs require SDK 19+.